# I want to setblock faraway, but it won't place them

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to setblocks far away, but it just won't place them, but when I set them nearby the command blocks it sets them. Is it lag or a limit in distance?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it says something like "You cannot place blocks out of the world". This is because the chunk is not loaded. You have to tp to the chunk first, or load it some other way such as spreadplayers, then place the block.

Comment: well thats unfortunate

Comment: the chunk is not loaded, you have to load the chunk by other methods. for example, using structure block or spreadplayers commands.